# datepicker value is not changing on editing in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, datepicker

I'm developing database application in wp7,where i using datepicker to store the date value.when i was  add a  record,it works perfectly,but during updating time when I'm editing the record,the datepicker value never changes.it contains the same value,how to make it as changeable?

Comment: please provide code that can replicate this behaviour.

Comment: on editing the record,i set `datepicker1.value=data[0].date`.So it retrieve the values from the database.After that when i changed the value in datepicker popup window its get changed when i click OK and the datepicker still holds the value which is came from record